# Is there any sect or school that believe vedas are authored by humans?

Tags: vedas, moksha, sects

Apparently all the schools believe that vedas are either authorless or are authored by God.

But is there any sect that believe that vedas are authored by **enlightened** humans.

---

<sup>By *"enlightened"* I mean the one who knows about Brahman ( i. e  Moksha)</sup>

Comment: No. If it is written by an enlightened human, it immediately classified as smriti.

Comment: @GIRIBLR there is [scholar on the YouTube](https://youtu.be/LoUhRjgWo_M) that say this vedas are written by humans(enlightened humans)

Comment: There are hundred of scholars in youtube telling hundreds of things. I thought your question was specific to the six darshanas. Ask him to quote from any sutras of the six darshanas. We can only go the by the sutras of the darshanas and their commentaries. Which one says humans wrote the vedas?

Comment: @GIRIBLR no one, that's why I asked this question. Most of the Hindus who claim they are **logical** say all scriptures are man made. Even a scholar on quora say this.

Comment: @GIRIBLR I one's showed a "logical" Hindu a verse from the Upanishads that's clearly say's vedas are not the product of human mind. He said by the product of the human mind they mean the product of an ordinary mind and not a realized mind. This is also the opinion of a guru.

Comment: This is an Indological standpoint only. Mīmāṁsā & Advaita hold that Veda is authorless, while Nyaya-Vaiśeṣika holds that Veda is authored by Īśvara. Yuktidīpikā & Sāṅkhyatattvakaumudī  (comms. on Sāṅkhyakārikā) both hold Veda to be authorless.